# Subcomponent.Builder -> Factory when using seedInstance to bind instance data

Tags: android, upgrade, dagger-2

I have an inherited code project that I am working on updating to the latest version of Dagger (2.25.2)

I want to switch from using the deprecated  `@Subcomponent.Builder` to the newer `@Subcomponent.Factory`. My one sticking point is how to handle binding for instance variables to my view model. The current pattern is the same as is described in this blog post: https://medium.com/@minakamel/how-to-inject-bundle-arguments-to-viewmodel-607429829cf0

Basically using `seedInstance` to get the instance then using `BindsInstance`:

```
@Subcomponent.Builder
abstract class Builder: AndroidInjector.Builder<ExampleActivity>() {

    abstract override fun build(): ExampleComponent

    @BindsInstance
    abstract fun currency(currency: String): Builder

    override fun seedInstance(instance: ExampleActivity) {
       currency(instance.getCurrencyFromBundle())
    }
}
```

What I have been unable to find are very many examples of overriding the `create` method for `@Subcomponent.Factory` to bind the instance data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind an instance using **factory** you need to pass it as an **argument** to factory method -

```
@Subcomponent.Factory
 interface Builder: AndroidInjector.Factory<ExampleActivity>() {

    fun create(@BindsInstance currency : String) : YourSubcomponentType

}
```

And the create method needs to return your SubComponent Type.

Comment: Two issues still:
1. If I use abstract class, I am asked to provide a function body. Should it be an interface?
2. Once I add an @BindsInstance, I am no longer overriding anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: 1. Yes my bad. I have updated the answer. 
2. Subcomponent Factory just needs to have a single method that returns Subcomponent type. Yes, you are not overriding anything.

Comment: I got that to work. What I still don't understand is if there is a way to still do a "seedInstance" where it binds from data available in the instance before injecting.